# Designing a contract for plugins

Tags: c#, plugins

I was thinking about designing a proper contract for future plugins creation for an application I'm currently working on. Basically the idea is to define an interface, but I want the application to be aware of plugins that currently presented to the system and to show the user a nice list of plugins with their names and a brief descriptions which ofcourse the developer of the plugin should provide, the user of the application shouldn't be able to alter this easily so an additional config file is not an option. I don't want to use the class name of filename of the assembly for this. Also I think that it should be accessable without instantiating the plugin, but maybe through reflection, something like: `assembly.GetType(type).GetProperty("Name").GetValue(null, null).ToString();`. Ofcourse I could provide some logic to check for existance something like `if(assembly.GetType(type).GetProperty("Name") != null)`, but this is not a good idea either, because if the property does not exist the end user won't have an idea of what that plugin does, not even what it's name is.
Now, it should behave like a static property, but static is not overridable so it seems that I cannot declare it as a part of an interface nor in an abstract class. Maybe I'm on wrong way, and it only looks like a static property and I can achive this functionality through another approach. So the brief question might be *"How to enforce the third party developer to provide some meta information about his plugin"*. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with two interfaces:

`IAddIn` for be the main interface that all add-ins will implement.

`IAddInInfo` for be the interface providing the metadata of the add-in (name, publisher, description version etc.)

Each add-in should implement both of these. An `IAddInInfo` implementation could be like this:

```
public class ScannerAddInInfo : IAddInInfo
{
    public string Name { get { return "Scanner"; } }

    public string Description { get { return "Add-in for acquiring images from a scanner device"; } }
}
```

To ensure that all implementations of add-ins come with metadata, you can make `IAddIn` a generic interface like:

```
public interface IAddIn<T> where T : IAddInInfo
{
    T Info { get; }

    //Continue with the rest of the members you would want every add-in to have.
}
```

Then the scanner add-in implementation would be:

```
public class ScannAddIn : IAddIn<ScannerAddInInfo>
{
    private ScannerAddInInfo _info = new ScannerAddInInfo();

    public ScannerAddInInfo Info { get { return _info; } }

    //Continue with the rest of the IAddIn implementation.
}
```

Then you could load the add-in assembly from a special add-in folder and create instances of the types implementing `IAddInInfo` and show the info from the discovered add-ins in your application. Note that no add-ins are created yet. To do so you will need to add some more reflection to find the types implementing `IAddIn<ScannerAddInInfo>`.

To make this simpler you could add the add-in type name to the `IAddInInfo` interface or something like that.

The only drawback to this approach is that you will have to load all assemblies found in your special add-in folder even if they do not include any add-ins.

To avoid this you could try [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil#Documentation). You then will have to do something like this:

```
AssemblyDefinition ad = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyPath); 

foreach (TypeDefinition td in ad.MainModule.GetTypes()) 
{ 
    if (td.BaseType != null && td.BaseType.FullName == "MyNamespace.MyAddInBase") 
    {         
        return true; 
    } 
}
```

To load the assemblies you can use [Assembly.LoadForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8c4tzhc.aspx) and to create instances of the add-ins and add-in infos, one of the [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) overloads.

Good luck.

Comment: This is an interesting approach indeed, but... It still doesn't prevent the 'Name' and 'Description'('Version', etc...) properites from being depended or based on fields(that could be changed), or some extra logic.
Though the possibility of instantiating only the metadata class, is very interesting.

Comment: Also have a look at http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata. It explains how MEF handles metadata. I have used MEF with lazy exports that include metadata. Then you simply check the metadata and not the exported instance because it will be loaded. Only when you want to load the add-in, you access the exported value.

Answer (score 0):

To add some 'meta data' to your plugins, you can use attributes. Create a custom attribute for your plugins and read out the information with reflection and show it in your application.

More info about attributes:

[Creating Custom Attributes (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx)

[Accessing Attributes by Using Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx)

Comment: Thought about that, but how do you define the desired attributes in a contract way, how do you let the developer know what attributes should be applied to his plugin(what meta-data do you expect the plugin to provide you)? Even if you apply an attribute on an interface, I'm not sure how it will help - the third party developer should provide the information, thus he should know somehow what attributes to apply to his plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you should do is basically define your interface and expect other people to implement their concrete classes and give that runtime object to you somehow (your predefined methods, configuration etc.)

But there is some mechanism called dependency injection. That allows you to define your interface and your entry points while a "system" takes care of matchmaking your entry points and implementers' concretes. There is "System.ComponentModel.Composition" namespace for this purpose.

I knew there was a framework called "Unity" doing such job. I guess composition namespace is somewhat a simplified version of unity. You can check help for "ImportAttribute" and "ExportAttribute" classes for some cue.

Comment: The "System.ComponentModel.Composition" (which is part of Managed Extensibility Framework(MEF)), and Unity both provide an implementation of the dependency injection pattern. But I'm not sure that it's a good idea to involve monsters to solve tiny problems. Just trying to find the right technique to make the third-party developer aware of what I will look for, and not only the EntryPoint and so, but also some meta-data. But thanks.

Comment: If you want to import a lot of interfaces, dependency injection frameworks lets you roll tbh. I used import/export attributes for some .net4. But if you are targeting something less than v4 than you are right to be curious about referencing another lib. I tend to make my business objecs in a way that they always are initialized with a service provider. If there is anything they need they look-up for the service they need and they go on. In those terms you just need to have a service with Register method which is only registering plug-in's service back to the provider.

Comment: I've implemented a simple dependency injection which is enough for current case. Also I'm trying to make the code as simple as possible and self-explanatory, therefore, I tend not to use frameworks just to use them, if the program doesn't utilize most of the possibilities of the framework. Besides I want to figure out, how specification of meta data could be enforced on implementators. Just trying to learn...

Comment: It depends on your implementation. I used to load dlls only in a certain folder. And while loading dlls if there is a type with my attributes (yes, attributes should be defined in a common assembly, like a framework of your own) I'd load that type as my plug-in. If I was looking for a certain plug-in to be implemented but not I threw exceptions. If not my app works silently, because that is a plug after all, if nothing is pushed in system should work unless it's one of the power plugs.

Comment: Yes, what your are describing here is somewhat similar to what I'm doing here. But the thing I'm trying to figure out is how do you make third-side developer aware of your requirement for certain attributes? To make him implement some methods we have interfaces and abstract classes, but how can you specify the attributes the object expected to carry? Otherwise, the devolper receives an interface, without implementing all the desired methods, you won't load his plugin, and this is obvious, but he won't know about the attributes that should be attached to the class.

Comment: Actually its implementers' responsibility to implement your interfaces. If your interface is only the attributes you provide, then as a result of such loose-coupling, implementers should check your documentation to match the interface. Since attributes are just meta-data about the code, there is nothing to enforce them I know of.

Comment: That's right, but at least implemeter sees what my interface requires to imlpement without any documentation. So I'm looking for a way to explicitly declare somehow that I expect to receive some additional information.  Neither do I know any way to do so, that's why I'm asking more experienced people for help.